# Filtering a datatable by values rather than displayed labels

Tags: r, datatable

The (toy) shiny app displays this datatable (**code below**).

[image]

The values of `var` are `-1`, `0`, `1` (the table can thus be sorted), but labels (`negative`, `zero`, `positive`) are displayed for the sake of aesthetics.

However, I need to use the numeric values rather than the labels in the search bar. Can you help me ?

Note: I know it might seem counter-intuitive to use values rather than labels in the search bar, but in the real app it does make sense.

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("my_table")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data.frame(
      var = factor(
        x      = c(-1, 0, 1),
        levels = c(-1, 0, 1),
        labels = c("negative", "zero", "positive")))
  }, rownames = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why not add a new column in the dataframe which has the values of the labels ?